# How do I expand my PHP 404 page to include the URL that was not found?

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

My custom 404 page contains the following PHP:

```
$to = "example@gmail.com";

$subject = "404 Error Page";

$from = "404@example.html\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $from);
```

I would like `$message` to contain the URL that produced the 404 error.

If that is possible, please modify the PHP accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

If that is your entire script, currently you don't even have anything assigned to the variable `$message`

Add a line before `mail()`

```
$message = "Error 404 from " . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
```

You can find all the `$_SERVER` variables in the PHP manual at https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

But the `$from` value in `mail()` is wrong anyway, that should contain additional header data - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php see `Example #2 Sending mail with extra headers.`